# Wercker setup environment step error: Guest command failed with exit code -1: mkdir -p "/pipeline"

Tags: android, wercker

I'm using wercker to do ci with my android application, which makes use of rxwen/android docker image.
But wercker always report the error message below in setup environment step.

`Guest command failed with exit code -1: mkdir -p "/pipeline"`

The last wercker log showed that it exited while extracting docker image.

```
Download complete: 62d952553a13                                                                  
Verifying Checksum: a8ef60972e3d                                                                                                 
Download complete: a8ef60972e3d                                                                                                  
Verifying Checksum: fe9f7f434a61                                                                                                 
Download complete: fe9f7f434a61                                                                                                  
Pull complete: 62d952553a13                                                                      
Verifying Checksum: 69ecce34af24                                
Download complete: 69ecce34af24                                 
Pull complete: 722fe23ca1d7                                     
Verifying Checksum: e8164c82c7ad                               
Download complete: e8164c82c7ad                                
Pull complete: fe9f7f434a61    
Pull complete: 69ecce34af24    
Pull complete: a8ef60972e3d    
Extracting: e8164c82c7ad (88%)
```

Anyone knows what does the error message imply?

Answer (score 1):

What docker image are you using? I had the same error when trying to use the "stable-alpine" image of nginx.

Turns out it was because the I needed to add the cmd: /bin/sh to the box step.

I.e. to fix it for me I had to change it from:

```
box: nginx:stable-alpine
```

to:

```
box:
    id: nginx:stable-alpine
    cmd: /bin/sh
```

Thanks to Antti Kupila on GitHub that help me find fix the issue. Link to GitHub issue: https://github.com/wercker/support/issues/275#issuecomment-255742729

Comment: I don't know if it works for me. I built my docker image and pushed to docker hub again. It worked. Although I think the error should be irrelevant to the docker image, since the docker image worked fine when I tested in locally.